# Version package error within google maps api

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, google-cloud-platform

I am running into new errors within my packages for integrating googlemapsapi into my pubspec.yaml.

I already tried downgrading them according to the flutter pub get in my terminal but nothing's working.

Here it is:

```yaml
name: google_maps_in_flutter
description: "A new Flutter project."
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.2.1 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_map: ^6.1.0
  google_maps: ^7.0.0
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.5.3
  js: ^0.7.0
  material_color_utilities: ^0.8.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_lints: ^3.0.1

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

Here's the output:

```
Because google_maps_in_flutter depends on google_maps ^7.0.0 which depends on js ^0.6.3, js ^0.6.3 is required.     
So, because google_maps_in_flutter depends on js ^0.7.0, version solving failed.
```

Does anyone know if google maps api still works, or if there is another alternative to maps with flutter? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried changing from `js: ^0.7.0` to `js: ^0.6.3`?

Comment: Yes, and then this pops up: Because google_maps_in_flutter depends on flutter from sdk which depends on material_color_utilities 0.5.0, material_color_utilities 0.5.0 is required.
So, because google_maps_in_flutter depends on material_color_utilities ^0.8.0, version solving failed.